# Run a specific macro in different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with more than 300+ excel files and what I want to open each of the excel files inside the folder and run specific macro that's already stored in each of the excel files, save it, close it and move to the next file.

The macro which is stored in each excel file is connected to other macros inside the workbook, you could call it like a Main macro, so for example If I just tried to run the Main macro, without the macros it's connected, to all the files at the same time, it just wouldn't work, because it is connected to other macros. The code below is what I've done so far, but it doesn't work as intended

```
Sub run_mYearChange
   
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim wPath As String, wQuan As Long, n As Long
Dim fso As Object, folder As Object, subfolder As Object, wFile As Object



With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    wPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With


Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set folder = fso.getfolder(wPath)

wQuan = folder.Files.Count
n = 1
For Each wFile In folder.Files
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing folder : " & folder & ". File : " & n & " of : " & wQuan
    If Right(wFile, 4) Like "*xlsm*" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wFile)
        Application.Run "'C:\test2\*.xlsm*'!mYearChange.YearChangeFunction" 
        wb.Save True
        wb.Close True
    End If
    n = n + 1
Next

Set fso = Nothing: Set folder = Nothing: Set wb = Nothing

MsgBox "End"

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

End Sub
```

I'm trying to find a solution everywhere and without luck. In this website there also hasn't been anything similar to what I'm asking. I would love all the help I could get, I'm kind of desperate, because nothing works.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the file name for each file opened.

Untested:

```vb
Sub run_mYearChange
   
'snipped....

Dim wPath As String, n As Long, f

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    wPath = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
if right(wPath, 1) <> "\" then wPath  = wPath & "\" 

f = Dir(wPath & "*.xlsm")
Do While Len(f) > 0
    With Workbooks.Open(wPath & f)
        Application.Run "'" & .Name & "'!mYearChange.YearChangeFunction"
        .Close True 'save
    End With
    n = n + 1
    f = Dir()
Loop

MsgBox "End"

'snipped...

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works just as intended! Awesome!